# Deployment of contract and calling its function is taking too much fees

Tags: smart-contract, evm, transaction-fees

I have configured the transaction fees to be approximately 40. However, when deploying a smart contract on an EVM-compatible chain, the fees amount to be 2300, and when calling this function, the charge is 150. How can I adjust the fees for both scenarios?